# Can't start MYSQL after changing directories

Tags: mysql, database, directory

So I started running out of space on my linux hard disk. I added another hard drive and now I want to change the MySQL directories. So instead of saving the data into the old hard drive, it saves it into the new hard drive. The new hard drive is mounted as /Data/

I looked several ways to do it, and I followed each and every instruction. But every time I followed the instructions I get an error ***"ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'"***

I tried moving the directory and then linking the old directory to the new one. Same error.

I tried moving the whole directory and changing the my.cnf file under etc to point at the new directory, I even changed the line socket=/Data/mysql/mysql.sock still the same error.

**Also, I did make sure all the ownerships were mysql:mysql

It fails to start each time. So I end up moving everything back to where it was and it starts successfully. I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your mysql logfile?

Comment: Is the new directory `mysql:mysql` ?

Comment: This is just to check, did your mysql server instance crashed the last time when it ran out of disk space? If so, then your old mysql.sock file still exists. Make sure the old mysql.sock file is deleted before you start mysql server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. No my server didn't crash. Like I mentioned, I can start it successfully if I leave everything as default. But as soon as I try to move the directory it won't start.

Answer (score 3):

In the my.cnf you need to add the socket path in two places: 
In the [mysql] and in the ->[client]<- section.

Here is a typical global option file:

[client]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: Confirmed was required after installing, migrating to a different directory and starting mysql. Only to realized I moved it to the wrong place and this was the missing part to get it running after the second move.

Answer (score 1):

Once you move everything to the new folder you need to make sure that the folder has permissions and ownership mysql:mysql.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did check all the ownerships and made sure all of them are mysql:mysql

Comment: Is there anything else in /var/log/mysql/mysql.log or error.log?

Comment: What OS it is installed on?

Comment: The Operating System is CentOS

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is not one you get from starting mysql with things in the wrong place, but from the fact that you need to modify the socket location in the `[client]`, `[mysqld] and any other location it shows up in, under my.cnf

Comment: I changed the socket file to the new destination under [mysqld] however [client] doesn't exist in my my.cnf file. Should I just add [client]?

Comment: There may be another location where it is configured, but even the client has to know where to connect to by default (if you don't put -h ).

Comment: I just tried to add [client] to the file and it still failed to start.     [root@localhost etc]# service mysqld start
mysMySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]       
[root@localhost etc]# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Data/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: in your my.cnf do you have option: basedir=/var/lib?

Comment: No [mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: This is the default, whenever I move the mysql folder, I make changes to the datadir and to socket. And then it doesn't start

Comment: So do you stop it before making the changes?

Comment: Yes. service mysqld stop. Then after I make changes, I try to start the service and it doesn't start.

Comment: Is the `mysql` database present in the new directory?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to just remove mysql and install in a new directory? Im in the process of building this server and so far I have had no luck in finding the solution. And I have begun to lose hope :/

Comment: Certainly, but if you install from prebuilt binaries, they tend to have certain assumptions built in.

Comment: Why not do this, symlink your new directory to a folder under /var/lib/mysql, leave the socket file as it is, but move the datadir to your new subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether still there are some mysqld process remained or not ?

```
# ps aux | grep mysqld
```

kill all mysqld process (Wait for 10 seconds so that it shut down cleanly):

```
# killall mysqld mysqld_safe
```

If you still able to see more than run this command :

```
killall -9 mysqld mysqld_safe
```

Restart mysqld:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: Hi Brice, could you maybe explain how your answer relates to the issue the asker is concerned about, which is mysql not starting when it configured to use non-standard locations?